# How does casting spells look in Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay?

Tags: magic, wfrp-2e, wfrp

I would like to know more about how casting spells works on a physical level in the second edition of Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay.

From the books I've learned that casting a spell requires saying some words. Being gagged or having your mouth injured makes it more complicated or impossible to cast spells. I've learned that armor makes casting spells more difficult, and it's apparently possible to use components to help in casting.

Things I'd like to understand better:

1. Are there any gestures required? If yes, how clear do they have to be?  If no how is it that armor impairs spellcasting?
2. What does a wizard have to do to make use of components? Do they have to touch the components during spellcasting or is it enough to have them "formally in possession"?
3. Is it possible to tell that a wizard is casting spells by looking at them (without Second Sight)?  Are the gestures and words obvious enough to be seen by onlookers?
4. Are there are any differences in the above for divine, dark and witch lores?

(This may be considered more than one question. I decided to ask it together as it is one general matter, but if I'm wrong, please let me know. I will split it. ;) )

Comment: This should probably be four different questions.  As a suggested breakdown: "What kind of gestures are necessary for casting wizard spells in WHFRP?" (Covers whether gestures are required, how obvious they are, and the bit about the armor.)  "What does a WHFRP wizard have to do to use spell components?", "How obvious is the spoken component of a wizard spell in WHFRP?", and "are there any differences in ho obvious spellcasting is between wizard, divine, dark, and withc lores in WHFRP?"  I would suggest you edit this into one of them, and post the other three separately.

Comment: The main question is a duplicate of [What does it look like when a wizard casts a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108670/what-does-it-look-like-when-a-wizard-casts-a-spell). But you may ask for more information in a new question.